# Bookshelfjs: How to query specific fields within join statements?

Tags: mysql, node.js, bookshelf.js

I was wondering how would it be possible to do a join such as the following using Bookshelfjs.

`SELECT a.id, a.name, b.test, b.id FROM b JOIN a ON a.id = b.a_id;`

I currently have this:

```
ModelA
  .query(function(qb) {
    qb.select('a.id', 'b.id' /*  etc */).from('a').join('b', 'a.id', 'b.a_id');
  })
  .fetchAll()
  .then(function() {})
  .catch(function() {
  })
```

The only problem with this is that I get everything back, and when i run `qb.debug()` I see that something along the `a.*` is appended. What can I/ should I do to get rid of that `a.*`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out. The query builder is really just adds the flexibility of specifying the query params.

I just had to do using raw `db.knex().select().leftJoin()`